# on Windows, create shortcuts with specific attributes

Tags: windows, shortcuts, batch-file

I'm looking for a way of programatically ( from a batch file ) creating shortcuts to `cmd` ( or other command line utilities ).

This can be easily achieved using SHORTCUT.EXE ( found in [ENVARS.EXE](http://download.microsoft.com/download/win95upg/tool_g/1.0/w95/en-us/envars.exe) ), but I cannot specify parameters such as the font to be used by the console window, the background/font colour, or the maximum scrolling lines.

How can such customized shortcuts be created from within a script ?

---

**update**
I experienced random crashes with ENVARS.EXE's SHORTCUT.EXE, it seems this tool was built for Win95 and has issues on newer platforms. Instead, I used [this](http://www.optimumx.com/download/Shortcut.zip) tool, it has a very similar syntax, supports the same options and works well.

I'm now looking into [Shellify](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shellify/), it seems to be more advanced and has a more standard way of specifying options. ( with dashes instead of `/` ). It does require .NET framework, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is not possible.

I tried other tools, but all of them only support the standard options. [Shellify](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shellify/) seems to be the most capable shortcut tool, supporting many advanced settings, but it still lacks the option to set the attributes  I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to examine the shortcut file with a hex editor and try to form such a file.

(You might have more succes on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com))